# Does it make sense to have properties like Option[List[...]] when the List container supports the property of empty?

Tags: scala

Does it make sense for class properties or function parameters that are like:

```
Option[List[String]]
Option[Map[String,String]]
```

Does wrapping it in an option provide more composability or since the container e.g. List and Map supports being empty there is no point in making it an `Option`?

Is it more efficient to have `Option` since it can be a `None` versus having a `List.empty` or `Map.empty`?

Comment: No, it is not more efficient, because both `Nil` and the empty map are also constants. Actually is the opposite, since now you have an additional wrapper; but not a big deal. - Whenever it makes sense or not, depends on your use case, there are moments when it is important to differentiate no data from empty data, for example getting the orders of client where `None` may imply the client doesn't exist or is bad registered and a `Some(List.empty)` may imply the users is right but doesn't have any orders right now. However, in general, `Some(empty)` and `None` are redundant.

Comment: Now, what is very common is an `Option[NonEmptyCollection]` since that removes the ambiguity and gives stronger guarantees.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I enjoy your feedback/help, why don't you respond in an answer instead of comments so you can get more recognition i.e. points etc. and especially when your comment is more of an answer :)

Comment: Because technically this is an opinion based question and answer which is _"bad"_ according to the rules :p

Answer (score 1):

It depends ;)

`Option` is also a collection - it just can't have more than 1 element (but it can have 0). So it usually doesn't make sense to wrap another collection in `Option`.

However, it depends on what it represents and what semantics it conveys. Is `None` and empty `List` the same? Or maybe it matters that the `List` is there, but it's empty? And it's different than when the `List` is not there?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on a use case. An empty list could actually mean something different than absence of a list.

Does `Option[Int]` make sense? Maybe not, if you just want to represent a number of candies (0 will do). But what if you are looking for a maximum element of a list, which happens to be empty? `None` would be much more appropriate in this case than 0.

Same with lists and other things. If you are listing brands of candy in someone's pocket, sure, you can use `Nil` to cover the case of a poor shmuck who doesn't have any.

But what if we wanted to describe, say a store inventory?
`def listBrandsInInventory(product: String = "candy"): List[String]`
What if this is a bookstore, and doesn't carry candy at all? Sure, you could argue, that nobody needs a store that does not carry candy, or you could still just return `Nil` (and it wouldn't even be lying), but there are two *different* situations here: either all candy is sold out, or we don't carry candy at all (don't bother to call tomorrow). If you'd like to distinguish between the two, `Option[List]` comes handy.